# how could I display the full information to string in the program.cs?

Tags: java, c#, arraylist, transactions, bank

I have the 3 classes below but for some reason I cannot display the transaction type and amount, I also cannot output the transaction history

CurrentAccount c1 = new CurrentAccount("234555",1000,  234, **TransactionType.Deposit)**; // the part in bold is not displayed

see the output below: 
234545 account number 100 overdraft.**System.Collections.ArrayList Transaction history.**

how could I correct my classes to display the transaction history correctly?

Please see below full classes

```
abstract class BankAccount
{
    protected string AccountNumber { get; } // read property
    protected double Balance { get; set; } //read and write property

    public BankAccount(string _accountNumber)
    {
        this.AccountNumber = _accountNumber;
        this.Balance = 0;
    }

    public virtual void MakeDeposit(double amount)
    {
        Balance = Balance + amount;
    }
    public virtual void MakeWithdraw(double amount)
    {
       Balance =  Balance - amount;
    }

  }
}


class CurrentAccount : BankAccount
{
    private double OverdraftLimit { get; } // read only property    

    public ArrayList TransactionHistory = new ArrayList();

    public CurrentAccount(string AccountNumber,  double OverdraftLimit, double amount, TransactionType type) : base(AccountNumber)
    {
        this.OverdraftLimit = OverdraftLimit;

        TransactionHistory.Add(new AccountTransaction(type, amount));           
    }

    public override void MakeDeposit(double amount) // override method 
    {
        Balance += amount;
        TransactionHistory.Add(new AccountTransaction(TransactionType.Deposit, amount));
    }
    public override void MakeWithdraw(double amount)
    {            
        if (Balance + OverdraftLimit > 0)
        {
            Balance -= amount;
            TransactionHistory.Add(new AccountTransaction(TransactionType.Withdrawal, amount));
        }

        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Insufficient Funds");
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
       // print the transaction history too
        return AccountNumber + " account number " + OverdraftLimit + " overdraft." + TransactionHistory + " Transaction history.";
    }
}
}

{ 
enum TransactionType
{
    Deposit, Withdrawal
}


class AccountTransaction
{
    public TransactionType type { get; private set; }      // deposit/withdrawal
    private double Amount { get; set; }

    public AccountTransaction (TransactionType type, double _amount)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.Amount = _amount;
    }



    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "type" + type + "amount" + Amount;
    }

}
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CurrentAccount c1 = new CurrentAccount("234555",1000,  234, **TransactionType.Deposit)**; // this part is not displayed
        CurrentAccount c2 = new CurrentAccount("234534", 12000, 345, **TransactionType.Withdrawal)**; // this part is not displayed
        CurrentAccount c3 = new CurrentAccount("234545", 100,  456, **TransactionType.Withdrawal)**; // this part is not displayed
        Console.WriteLine(c1);
        Console.WriteLine(c2);
        Console.WriteLine(c3);

    }
}
}
```

Output from the console: 
234555 account number 1000 overdraft.System.Collections.ArrayList Transaction history.
234534 account number 12000 overdraft.System.Collections.ArrayList Transaction history.
234545 account number 100 overdraft.System.Collections.ArrayList Transaction history.

Please could you help me to output the correct information.

Comment: Please read [ask] and format your code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is happening bevause you have the string method override. The only thing that I though is that you need to override tostring method in bank class to because you are inheriting from bank. Try it and tell to me if this works.